# How to use FTX FIX protocol API (in python) to place an order?

Tags: python, fix-protocol

I am new to FIX protocol and was trying to use it to place an order with FTX exchange. I downloaded the sample code from https://github.com/ftexchange/ftx/tree/master/fix and wrote the following main.py:

```
from ftx.fix.client import *
client = FixClient('tcp+ssl://fix.ftx.com:4363', target_id='FTX', 
    client_id=my_key,subaccount_name=my_subaccount_name)
temp = client.login(my_secret)
temp1 = client.send_order(symbol = 'BTC-PERP', side = 'buy', price = 36000.0, size = 0.001)
print ("done")
```

The code runs smoothly (process finished with exit code 0) with no error message whatsoever. However the trade was not placed with the subaccount. What did I miss?

Comment: This is not really an answer so I'll simply leave a comment here. Check this code sample: https://bitbucket.org/xtrd/xtrd_demos/src/master/python_trader/